# Multiple conditions in mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to filter the **products** on the basis of **price**, **brand**, and **category**. But none of them is required. So the user can filter the products on the basis of only price or price and brand. How to write this in **mySQL** using **queries** only. I have searched a lot but found the solution with the help of Stored Procedures.

If I write this query `select * from product where brandid = 1 AND price = 10 and categoryid = 5`. it will fetch 2 products which satisfy the where clause.

But if user doesn't want to filter the product on the basis of brand (lets say), then what will b the query? `select * from product where brandid = null AND price = 10 and categoryid = 5`... this will not work as I dont want to search products with brandid null. What I want is to remove that particular clause from where condition. So what my expected query is `select * from product where price = 10 and categoryid = 5`

Comment: So are you saying that you already wrote a stored proc to handle this?  How are you calling this code, directly or maybe from an application?

Comment: Show sample data, expected Output and code you have written

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Why do you think i am the downvoter? And also how can this question be answered without any knowledge about the db structure?

Comment: @Ruchiyadav Please add These informations to your question using the edit link, not as comment

Comment: @Jens Ok.......

Comment: to check against `null`, you have to use `is null` not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the query incrementally. Here it is in Ruby (since you didn't tag a programming language), but the logic is quite language-independent.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM products"
filters = []
params = []

if price_min
  filters << "price >= ?"
  params << price_min
end

if price_max
  filters << "price <= ?"
  params << price_max
end

if brand
  filters << "brand = ?"
  params << brand
end

# ...

unless filters.empty?
  query += " WHERE " + filters.join(' AND ')
end
```

Comment: Replace `<<` with `push`, add some braces, nothing of importance changes.

Comment: ok. but if the user didn't select anything in Price so the value for price is null. Now query runs for price== null. And no data is there with price - null

Comment: Did you miss the `if`? If the parameter is falsy, the corresponding clause doesn't get added to the query. If you don't select anything, you just get the base `SELECT * FROM products`. (I suppose for JavaScript you should also change `unless filters.empty?` to `if (filters.length)`...